# Можно ли получить сертификат разработчика Apple и Provisioning Profile без макбука?

Tags: ios

Насколько я понял для Provisioning Profile нужен Device ID устройства.
IPAD есть и ещё IPOD старый :D

Comment: Ладно, если простым языком - да, Вы сможете опубликовать приложение в AppStore даже если у Вас нет устройства на базе iOS. Если же у Вас хакинтош и вы хотите собрать приложение, то это уже другое вопрос. Уточните пожалуйста что Вы хотите сделать.

Comment: а просто нажать download не работает?

Comment: @RomanPodymov Собрать приложение хочу через Phonegap Build.